# Bring text of an anchor tag with data-role=button in center using css

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I want to bring text of my button in center using CSS.
I have tried using **text-align** as well as **vertical-align** but nothing is working. Please advice. 
This is my button css

```
.button_eclipse {
width: 100px !important;
height: 100px !important;
border-radius: 50% !important;
background: rgb(247,107,32) !important;
color: rgb(255,255,255) !important;
}
```

And in this template i am creating buttons

```
<div>
<a data-role="button" id="btn_gotohomepage" class="button_eclipse"><%= val_btn_gotohomepage %></a>
<a data-role="button" id="btn_gotologinpage" class="button_eclipse"><%= val_btn_gotologinpage %></a>
<a data-role="button" id="btn_gotolistpage" class="button_eclipse"><%= val_btn_gotolistpage %></a>
</div>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HYjeG/4/

**HTML :**

```
<div>
    <a data-role="button" id="btn_gotohomepage" class="button_eclipse">Some text</a> 
</div>
```

**CSS :**

.button_eclipse {
        width: 100px !important;
        height: 100px !important;
        border-radius: 50% !important;
        background: rgb(247,107,32) !important;
        color: rgb(255,255,255) !important;
    }

```
.button_eclipse .ui-btn-inner {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    height: 80% !important;
}

.button_eclipse .ui-btn-inner  .ui-btn-text { 
    display: block !important;
    margin: 28px 0 0 -17px;
    width: 95px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for a quick and perfect answer. Its working, but 1 thing some sort of arc is coming around my button some unusual border at top of every button. Can you please help me remove that. You will be able to see if you change your page background color to some dark color. Please help me once again. @Gajotres

Comment: Give me few minutes to check it.

Comment: This should do it, take a look at my answer again.

Comment: The border which was visible as an arc now turned to a straight line at the top of button @Gajotres

Comment: Check it now. I have fixed inner DIV so that inner border no more looks like an arc, now it follows inner button border.

Comment: Perfect Thanks. And 1 last thing. Can you please tell me what attributes i should use to change font and font size of my text inside the button. Please help. @Gajotres

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am posting 1 more new question i am sure you will be able to help me with that one also. Please check. @Gajotres

Answer (score 0):

instead of using width and height use padding:

```
.button_eclipse {
    padding: 100px 100px !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    background: rgb(247,107,32) !important;
    color: rgb(255,255,255) !important;
}
```

That should work